# Inconsistent response from kubernetes api service and getting no route to host error sometimes

Tags: kubernetes, kube-proxy, kube-apiserver

I have configured kubernetes cluster using the steps as kubernetes the hard way by kelsey tower

Unfortunately i'm seeing inconsistent response when i hit the kubernetes service ip to check the version from worker nodes

here are my cluster details

```
root@kubem1:~# kubectl get no
NAME     STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
kubew1   Ready    <none>   14h   v1.18.3
kubew2   Ready    <none>   14h   v1.18.3
root@kubem1:~# kubectl get no -o wide
NAME     STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
kubew1   Ready    <none>   14h   v1.18.3   192.168.56.103   <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS   4.15.0-76-generic   containerd://1.2.9
kubew2   Ready    <none>   14h   v1.18.3   192.168.56.104   <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS   4.15.0-76-generic   containerd://1.2.9
root@kubem1:~# kubectl get svc -o wide
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE   SELECTOR
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.32.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   21h   <none>
root@kubem1:~# kubectl get po -n kube-system -o wide
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP           NODE     NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
coredns-589fff4ffc-mwrpk   1/1     Running   0          163m   10.200.1.5   kubew1   <none>           <none>
coredns-589fff4ffc-qps68   1/1     Running   0          163m   10.200.2.3   kubew2   <none>           <none>
root@kubem1:~#
```

From worker node,

Kube-proxy systemd config

```
cat /etc/systemd/system/kube-proxy.service 
[Unit]
Description=Kubernetes Kube Proxy
Documentation=https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/kube-proxy \
  --config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/kube-proxy-config.yaml
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

kube-proxy config yaml file

```
cat /var/lib/kube-proxy/kube-proxy-config.yaml
kind: KubeProxyConfiguration
apiVersion: kubeproxy.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
clientConnection:
  kubeconfig: "/var/lib/kube-proxy/kubeconfig"
mode: "iptables"
clusterCIDR: "10.200.0.0/16"
```

kube-proxy service status

```
    root@kubew2:~# service kube-proxy status
● kube-proxy.service - Kubernetes Kube Proxy
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kube-proxy.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-05-26 07:47:22 UTC; 9min ago
     Docs: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes
 Main PID: 11502 (kube-proxy)
    Tasks: 6 (limit: 1111)
   CGroup: /system.slice/kube-proxy.service
           └─11502 /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy --config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/kube-proxy-config.yaml

May 26 07:47:22 kubew2 kube-proxy[11502]: I0526 07:47:22.697056   11502 node.go:136] Successfully retrieved node IP: 192.168.56.104
May 26 07:47:22 kubew2 kube-proxy[11502]: I0526 07:47:22.699467   11502 server_others.go:186] Using iptables Proxier.
May 26 07:47:22 kubew2 kube-proxy[11502]: I0526 07:47:22.699748   11502 server.go:583] Version: v1.18.3
May 26 07:47:22 kubew2 kube-proxy[11502]: I0526 07:47:22.700110   11502 conntrack.go:52] Setting nf_conntrack_max to 131072
May 26 07:47:22 kubew2 kube-proxy[11502]: I0526 07:47:22.702569   11502 config.go:315] Starting service config controller
May 26 07:47:22 kubew2 kube-proxy[11502]: I0526 07:47:22.702786   11502 shared_informer.go:223] Waiting for caches to sync for service config
May 26 07:47:22 kubew2 kube-proxy[11502]: I0526 07:47:22.702922   11502 config.go:133] Starting endpoints config controller
May 26 07:47:22 kubew2 kube-proxy[11502]: I0526 07:47:22.703039   11502 shared_informer.go:223] Waiting for caches to sync for endpoints config
May 26 07:47:22 kubew2 kube-proxy[11502]: I0526 07:47:22.803627   11502 shared_informer.go:230] Caches are synced for endpoints config
May 26 07:47:22 kubew2 kube-proxy[11502]: I0526 07:47:22.804515   11502 shared_informer.go:230] Caches are synced for service config
root@kubew2:~#
```

Here is the problematic output.2,3 time its giving proper output and after that it is throwing error as no route host and again it is working

```
root@kubew2:~# curl -k https://10.32.0.1:443/version
{
  "major": "1",
  "minor": "18",
  "gitVersion": "v1.18.3",
  "gitCommit": "2e7996e3e2712684bc73f0dec0200d64eec7fe40",
  "gitTreeState": "clean",
  "buildDate": "2020-05-20T12:43:34Z",
  "goVersion": "go1.13.9",
  "compiler": "gc",
  "platform": "linux/amd64"
}root@kubew2:~# curl -k https://10.32.0.1:443/version
{
  "major": "1",
  "minor": "18",
  "gitVersion": "v1.18.3",
  "gitCommit": "2e7996e3e2712684bc73f0dec0200d64eec7fe40",
  "gitTreeState": "clean",
  "buildDate": "2020-05-20T12:43:34Z",
  "goVersion": "go1.13.9",
  "compiler": "gc",
  "platform": "linux/amd64"
}

root@kubew2:~# curl -k https://10.32.0.1:443/version
```

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.32.0.1 port 443: No route to host

```
root@kubew2:~# curl -k https://10.32.0.1:443/version
{
  "major": "1",
  "minor": "18",
  "gitVersion": "v1.18.3",
  "gitCommit": "2e7996e3e2712684bc73f0dec0200d64eec7fe40",
  "gitTreeState": "clean",
  "buildDate": "2020-05-20T12:43:34Z",
  "goVersion": "go1.13.9",
  "compiler": "gc",
  "platform": "linux/amd64"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.Since it is high availability setup,there are 2 nodes(end points) api service and unfortunately the other node 192.168.56.102 - kube-apiserver is not able to connect etcd which running on that node and whenever the curl command hits kubernetes service ip which  resolves to 192.168.56.102,i'm getting no route to host since its not able to get the date from node 2 etcd db

I have removed the etcd second node etcd memeber(192.168.56.102:2380) from kube-apiserver command line arqs -

```
--etcd-servers=http://192.168.56.101:2379,http://192.168.56.102:2380
```

Removed the second node from endpoints of kubernetes service

```
root@kubem1:~# kubectl get ep
NAME         ENDPOINTS                                 AGE
kubernetes   192.168.56.101:6443,192.168.56.102:6443   22h

root@kubem1:~# kubectl edit ep kubernetes
endpoints/kubernetes edited

root@kubem1:~# kubectl get ep kubernetes
NAME         ENDPOINTS             AGE
kubernetes   192.168.56.101:6443   22h
```

Now i'm able to get curl output properly without route to host